# Calling dust.render within handler function

Tags: dust.js

Is it bad style to call dust.render from within a handler?  Is there any problem associated with this?  For example:

```
function loadInner(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  dust.render("inner", {}, function(err, out) {
    chunk.write(out);
  });
}
```

Comment: What is this a handler for? A dust Helper?

Comment: it is basically another template.  just seems easier to call a function that calls dust.render rather than use partials - but i'm wondering if that is bad style.

Comment: Is the reason it's difficult because you have to already have the compiled template included on the page?  It sounds like you are including dust-full.js on your page and compiling templates on page load, which would be bad practice.  If this is the case, let's discuss a better solution.